# Cassandra join only on secondary index

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, rdd

Actualy i'm using spark and cassandra to run some jobs. I would to join an RDD with cassandra using joinWithCassandraTable.

In my case i need to do it only with secondary index but it's look like i have to add the partitionkey as well.

```
Myrdd.repartitionByCassandraReplica(keyspace, table)
  .joinWithCassandraTable(keyspace, table).on(SomeColumns(MY_KEY))
```

When MY_KEY is the partitionkey its work but not with the secondary index.  Do you have any idea how to do it?

From https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable  i got this:

> Compatibility of joinWithCassandraTable and other CassandraRDD APIs The result of a joinWithCassandraRDD is compatible with all of the standard CassandraRDD api options with one additional function, .on. Use .on(ColumnSelector) for specifying which columns to join on. Since .on only applies to CassandraJoinRDDs it must immediately follow the joinWithCassandraTable call.
>
> Joining on any column or columns in the primary key is supported as long as it can be made into a valid CQL query. This means the entire partition key must be specified and if any clustering key is specified all previous clustering keys must be supplied as well.